# Overlapping dates procedure in Postgres? I am trying to do this with OVERLAP but this doesnot work out?

Tags: postgresql

```
CREATE FUNCTION overlap_date() RETURNS trigger AS $overlap_date$
    DECLARE
        rec x%rowtype;

    BEGIN
        FOR rec IN
            SELECT start_date , end_date FROM x where c_id=NEW.c_id AND l_id=NEW.l_id
        LOOP
            IF (rec.start_date,rec.end_date) OVERLAPS (NEW.start_date, NEW.lapse_date) THEN
                RAISE EXCEPTION 'Date Ranges Overlap';
            ELSE
                RETURN NEW.effective_date;
        END LOOP;

    END;
$overlap_date$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Why don't you use an [exclusion constraint](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-EXCLUSION) - that will be **much** more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

There are some implementations problems with your trigger:

- it exits at the first iteration of the loop, ignoring the other rows in `rec`.
- it tries to return a column (`NEW.effective_date`) but a trigger must only return either the entire row (`NEW`), or NULL.

A more fundamental problem is that a trigger does not see the not-yet committed changes of other transactions, so it's subject to **race conditions** when there are multiple writers. A unique index is not subject to these race conditions, because it automatically serializes concurrent writers with locks.

This is why exclusion constraints should be used instead. These constraints are specifically meant for this kind of problem.